# in place of $addfield if use $project it's showing the same output then what is the difference between $addfield and $project in mongo db

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

please help me to know the difference in place of $project an $addFields if was giving $addFields or $project it was also giving the same output let me know what is the difference between $project and $addFields

Comment: can you please share the example you are using?

Answer (score 0):

`$addFields` adds new fields to documents. `$addFields` outputs documents that contain all existing fields from the input documents and newly added fields.

The `$addFields` stage is equivalent to a `$project` stage that explicitly specifies all existing fields in the input documents and adds the new fields.

`$addFields` has the following form:

```
{ $addFields: { <newField>: <expression>, ... } }
```